# OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 67 have to be processed first

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migrate, opshub

I am trying to do a test migration from a on-premise TFS2013 server to an Visual Studio Online environment, but am getting the error:

> OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 67 have to be processed first.

The changeset number mentioned in the error is a pretty big one, and maybe that has something to do with it. I would be happy if I could do the migration from starting point changeset 68 for example.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

While the OpsHub tool is very good at the happy path it does not have any advanced editing and resolutions. This is likely only going to change a little as they want to sell their main commercial tools (fair enough, its a free tool.)

However once you get outside of the happy path and you need that configuration capabilits you will need to try another tool. There are a few options in this space (in order of price):

1. [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) - This is a free tool nominally supported by the TFS product team. It can allow you to manually complete the pending check-in and then you can use that check-in number to resolve the conflict. You can also start the migration from a certain changeset.
2. [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/) - These are by far the cheapest and most capable migration tools for TFS to TFS in the source control space. They have a plethora of additional resolution tools that run on top of their platform to assist in diagnosing and resolving even the most complex issues.
3. [OpsHub Integration Tools](http://www.opshub.com/main/) - OpsHub is designed as a synchronisation tool and they have recently become involved in the migration market. I believe their tool to be at the expensive end of the spectrum.

I am sure that for some issues OpsHub will update their tool to support the scenario, however there are code migration scenarios that crap out in all of the tools and you have to do manual intervention. To my knowledge the free OpsHub tool does not support this.